# (identifier expected) getter/setter and objects

Tags: java, object, setter, getter

I've got a problem with my programm. When i try to compile following i just receive the message:

```
Tutorium.java:15: error: <identifier> expected
    public void settName(vorlesung.lectureName) {
                                              ^
```

So my Code:

Tutorium.java

```
public class Tutorium {
private Vorlesung vorlesung;
public String tName;
private int tNumber;


public int gettNumber() {
    return this.tNumber;
}

public String gettName() {
    return this.tName;
}

public void settName(vorlesung.lectureName) {
    this.tName = vorlesung.lectureName;
}

public String toString() {
    return (this.tName + ", " + this.tNumber);
}

public Tutorium(int tNumber){
    this.tNumber = tNumber; } }
```

Vorlesung.java

```
public class Vorlesung {
public String lectureName;
private int lectureNumber;
private int lecture;
private Dozent dozent;
private String lecturerlName;

public String getlectureName(){
    return this.lectureName;
}

public int lectureNumber(){
    return this.lectureNumber;
}

public int lecture(){
    return this.lecture;
}

public String getlecturer(){
    this.lecturerlName = dozent.lecturerlName;
    return this.lecturerlName;
}

public String toString() {
    return (this.lectureName + ", " + this.lectureNumber);
}

public Vorlesung(String lectureName, int lecture) {
    this.lectureName = lectureName;
    this.lecture = lecture +1;
    this.lectureNumber = this.lecture -1;
    this.lecturerlName = lecturerlName;
}}
```

My Main-Method:

```
public class MainVorlesung {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student student = new Student("STUDENTNAME", "STUDENTLASTNAME", 178, 1);
    Vorlesung vorlesung = new Vorlesung("Programmieren", 13341);
    Tutorium tutorium = new Tutorium(3);
    Dozent dozent = new Dozent("LECTURERFIRSTNAME", "LECTURERLASTNAME", 815);

    System.out.println(student.toString());
    System.out.println(vorlesung.toString());
    System.out.println(tutorium.toString());
    System.out.println(dozent.toString());

}}
```

My goal is to set the value of tName equal the value of vorlesung.lectureName.

Why can't i do this that way?

I appreciate every help. :)
Thanks

Comment: `settName(vorlesung.lectureName) {` ?? What is this trying to do? You had something in mind when you placed that strange method parameter in there -- what was it? Shouldn't that instead be `settName(String name) {`?

Comment: It works a heck of a lot better than what you have in there, trust me. Your parameter declaration is not valid Java. You need to show that attempt because the error message you just posted doesn't match the code I've mentioned.

Comment: Explain `"does not work"` please. That is not very useful, and does not give us enough information to allow us to help you.

Comment: Please **do not** edit your question in a way that makes existing answers for the previous version of your question invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your goal is:

> My goal is to set the value of tName equal the value of vorlesung.lectureName.

You should get rid of the setName method entirely since it will depend entirely on the vorlesung field and so should not be changeable. You should also get rid of the tName field, and instead change `getName()` to:

```
public class Tutorium {
    private Vorlesung vorlesung;
    // public String tName;  // get rid of
    private int tNumber;



    public String gettName() {
        if (vorlesung != null) {
            return vorlesung.getlecturer();
        }

        return null; // or throw exception
    }

    // *** get rid of this since you won't be setting names
    // public void settName(Vorlesung vorlesung) {
    //     this.tName = vorlesung.lectureName;
    // }
```

---

I have just now noticed that your Tutorium class does not have and absolutely needs a `setVorlesung(...)` method.

```
public void setVorlesung(Vorlesung vorlesung) {
    this.vorlesung = vorlesung;
}
```

Comment: @peter87: it should read `getlecturer()`. It's a method from the Vorlesung class. Most importantly, you need a `setVorlesung(...)` method for your class.

Answer (score 1):

For methods, the arguments that you pass in must have a declared value.

In this case, a String. So you need to change your method to this:

```
public void settName(String newLectureName) {
    this.tName = newLectureName;
}
```

Read more about what a java method is and how to create one here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm

Answer (score 1):

Change settName to

```
public void settName(String name) {
    this.tName = name;
}
```